# Angular 2 redirectTo with router not work

Tags: angular

I am developing my first app using angular 2 and I encountered strange problem.

I have my routes configuration like this:

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'login' },
{ path: 'login',  component: Login },
{ path: 'home',   component: Home }
];
```

and when I enter localhost:3000 I am automatically redirected to my localhost:3000/login , which is my login form page. When I enter my credentials and click submit router naviagation doesn't work ( no errors in console ), but suprisingly router works when I refresh localhost:3000/login.

I call router this way:

```
export class Login {
   constructor(public router: Router, public http: Http) {
   }

login(event, username, password) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //  ...
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
}
```

}

What could be wrong with this routes configurations ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to omit the leading slash:

```
this.router.navigate(['home']);
```

Also you might need to set the `pathMatch: 'full'` property on your redirect route.

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

Otherwise your route doesn't trigger when there are other routes with a deeper level available.

Comment: After removing slash it stopped working after refreshing as well

Comment: Did you include `pathMatch: 'full'`?

Comment: Yes, I added pathMatch

Comment: I can't see why it wouldn't work. Does it work, when you remove the redirect route? I think you're being redirected to login whichever route you navigate to.

Comment: When I remove redirect blank page appears since I don't have any component assigned to default path. I also can't remove redirectTo and add component to default path because it doesn't compile

Comment: what's "doesn't compile" mean? are you using the latest versions of angular and router?

Comment: Sorry it compiles from terminal, but Intellij show error Initilizer type .. is not assignable to variable RouterConfig. I am using angular 2.0.0-rc.3 and router 3.0.0-alpha.7

Comment: Just to be clear. You now have `{ path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' }` + the other two routes? If it doesn't work like that I have no idea, I'm sorry. Also I'm not familiar with the 3.0.0-alpha routers. I don't know how much the API has changed during alpha and beta releases

Comment: Yes. After upgrading to rc-05 and router to rc-1 it started to work. Thank you for your help

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Would you mind marking this as the answer? Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 15, redirectTo will not work alone without pathMatch property. It tells angular to redirect to the default path or named component when the path doesn't match with other routes.